# Assembly External Subroutines & Driver program

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

So I am trying to write some external subroutines in assembly to run along with a driver program that I wrote. I want to read in the program, through sysin, and also provide some instream assembly.

Here's the JCL part:

```
//SYSIN     DD  DSN=***.***.***,DISP=SHR
//*
//* SUBROUTINES HERE?
//*
/*
```

I understand the basics of entry and exit linkage, but do I need to have another DD statement for my instream assembly? Or, could I just start coding after I declare my `***.***.***` data set?

Comment: Why don't you just assemble the sub-routines separately?

Comment: And, to clarify a bit, after assembling, use the binder to bind everything together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have some code in a dataset and some other code in-stream, you can do that in your JCL as follows...

```
//SYSIN    DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=BLAH.BLAH
//         DD  *
[in-stream data]
//*
```

...but @Bill Woodger asks a good question, why not assemble the subroutines separately and link them in.  Personally, I would find that more "normal."

Comment: Oh I agree, but I'm working through a book, and this is one of the problems. I figured It would just be a good idea to know how to do it. Thanks for the help!